# Links to Facebook pages with Facebook's browser broken

Tags: iphone, facebook

The situation:

1) I created a post in Facebook to this page: http://calendar.dondley.com/official-westfieldma-facebook-pages/

2) The page contains a list of links back to Facebook pages, formatted like this: https://www.facebook.com/1519027881736551

The problem:

1) A user taps on the link to the webpage using the Facebook app on their iPhone

2) The Facebook app opens the web page in the Facebook browser.

3) User taps on one of the links that takes them back to Facebook.

4) User sees this:

[image: Broken link]

Additional info:

1) No problem on my Android Nexus 4 simulator and others have reported that it works OK on their Android. The problem only appears to happen with iPhone.

Any workaround or fix?

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to not use https://www.facebook.com/{page_id} but https://www.facebook.com/{page_link}

So instead of https://www.facebook.com/1234878723423 use https://www.facebook.com/WhateverLinkToPageIsHere